# In a bash script, replace character in string with multiple characters

Tags: bash, shell, raspbian, tr

I want to replace "." in this result: "172.16.0.25" with " dot ".

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash    
connection=`netstat -tn | grep :1337 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1`
#this returns "172.16.0.25"
replace=" dot "
final=${connection/./$replace}
echo "$final"
```

Which returns: `test.sh: 4: test.sh: Bad substitution`

I tried using `tr '.' ' dot '` but that only replaced the '.' with a space (' ')

I know this is a really dumb question, but I'm new to Shell Script.

Also, if it changes anything, I'm on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same with `awk` alone :

```
netstat -tn | awk '/:1337/{sub(/:.*/,"",$5);gsub(/\./," dot ",$5);print $5}'
```

If pattern `:1337` is matched, take the `5th` field. Now remove the `:number` part. Also replace `.` with  `dot` and print the field.

Comment: I do have a question though, is there anyway I could replace an enter/return in the string?

Comment: Can u provide a sample input and output? Now you r getting the different addresses in one line... is that the concern?

Comment: Input: "172.16.0.25 (ENTER)172.16.0.25" Output: "172.16.0.25 and 172.16.0.26"

Comment: You can use sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ and /g' .Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed

Answer (score 2):

```
connection=`netstat -tn | grep :1337 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sed 's/\./ dot /g'`
```

You can even simplify by staying in `awk`:

```
connection=`netstat -tn | awk '/1337:/ && !x { split($5, a, /:/); x = a[1]; gsub(/[.]/, " dot ", x); print x }'`
```

(I added `&& !x` to make sure only one row is fetched, just in case.)

Comment: and the second one returns " "

Comment: Hmm... could be something with Raspian... I believe it works on my end :(

Answer (score 2):

That line looks fine to me (although it will only replace the first dot; use `${connection//./$replace}` to replace all of them), so the most likely thing is that you're not actually using bash.

The bash error message has a lower case `b` in `bad substitution` and puts the word `line` before the line number. The error message shown looks like it is coming from `/bin/sh`.

If you are running the script with the command

```
sh test.sh
```

then the system will use `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

While @Amadan's answer nails it, I am posting a variation(just for enthusiasts), risking negative votes :)

```
connection=$(netstat -tn | grep :1337 | awk '{gsub("\.","dot", $5); print $5}' | cut -d: -f1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
final="${connection//./$replace}"
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
connection="172.16.0.25"
replace=" dot "
final="${connection//./$replace}"
echo "$final"
```

Output:

```
172 dot 16 dot 0 dot 25
```